# asp:textbox issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have Name textbox and Address textbox.  When page load, I use jQuery function go set disable some checkboxes and other textboxes.

They work perfect when I debug locally, but when publishing to production, users who have Read-Only permission cannot select and copy the Name textbox and Address textbox (these jquery function doesn't touch these 2 textboxes), these textboxes are just frozen (the Name textbox and Address textbox are disabled for readonly users - setting from the security page).

The developers who have full right don't have this issue.

I've tried to set focus from the code behind for those textboxes, none seems work.

In my page I set the disable compatibility mode  on IE .

Any help is really appreciated.

Edit:  This is my code

```
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
      <link href="../styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
      <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></scriptt>  
      <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form id="form" runat="server"
         <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" >Name:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
         <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" >Name:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNew" runat="server" Text="New?"></asp:CheckBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOld" runat="server" Text="Old?">&nbsp;                                                                </asp:CheckBox>&nbsp;
        </br>
       <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" >Type:</asp:Label>&nbsp;   
       <cc1:ELMSDropDownList ID="cboType" runat="server" AddEmpty="true" TableName="TYPE" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" >  

      <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" OnClick="cmdSave_Click"  
                                    Text="    Save    "></asp:Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      

     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">  
    function Changecbx()
    {
       if (strType=="something")
        {
            $("#chkNew").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#chkNew").prop("disabled", true);
        }
       return true; 
    }

    function Validate()
    {
        //jquery validation        
    }
    </body>
```

Here is my code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
          if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             cmdSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Validate()"); 
             cboType.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return Changecbx()"); 

             txtName. Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
             txtAddress. Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your goal exactly.

Comment: You should really be doing security stuff server side.  Otherwise people can just turn off their js to bypass your security features

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your issue: *"users who have Read-Only permission cannot select and copy the Name textbox and Address textbox"* -- it sounds like this it the problem you're trying to solve, but: *"the Name textbox and Address textbox are disabled for readonly users"* -- this makes it sound like it's intentional. Could you clarify please?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying my question.  The read-only users were able to select and copy the Name textbox and the Address textbox before.  After I put in a jquery function (I changed the page to compatibility mode to resolve the jquery issue), they can not select and copy those textboxes' text any more.   The jquery function works on the server, only selectable issue.  I wonder if my jquery afftects that.

Answer (score 1):

Set these inputs to be `readonly` instead of `disabled`, but style them so that they look disabled.

Comment: Yes, I did change the textbox to readonly on page load, but they are still not selectable.  I have to click 1 or 2 times somewhere in the form before I can select the text

Comment: @JennyLe - I cannot explain this without seeing any code.

Comment: I just added my code, thanks